# Почему не работает Json_decode в php?

Tags: php, json, null, decode

Вот пример скрипта

https://pastebin.com/BfkQf0NG

При использование json_decode в php, ничего не выводится

Я пробовал сам вписать json код, `$res=json_decode('{"Name":"Steve"}');`

```
Print_r($res);
```

И он вывел всё верно. Вчём причина?

Вот сам запрос, который не декодируется

```
﻿﻿[{"id":"123hi","First_name":"Данил","Last_name":"Такой-то","email":"kalinindanilq7734@gmail.com","status":"Hello.","avatar":"http:\/\/example.com","pol":"М","date_reg":"25\/03\/2019 00:30","date_login":"10\/06\/2019 00:40"}]
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95236/discussion-on-question-by-mr-danil----json-decode--php).

Comment: Смотрите официальную документацию, а также функцию json_last_error()

Comment: Я кажется понил почему не робит

Comment: Потому-что в запросе который я получаю есть какие то не печатаемые символы, а php эти символы не поддерживает, я на другом форуме прочитал. Вот токо как их убрать. Хм.

Comment: А json_last_error() выводит 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в JSON символ &#65279 в самом начале, он делает JSON невалидным и json_decode не может его распарсить.
&#65279 - это BOM (Byte Order Mark), удалите его и всё заработает.

```php
function remove_utf8_bom($str)
{
    return str_replace("\xEF\xBB\xBF",'',$str); 
}

$string = '[{"id":"123hi","First_name":"Данил","Last_name":"Такой-то","email":"kalinindanilq7734@gmail.com","status":"Hello.","avatar":"http:\/\/example.com","pol":"М","date_reg":"25\/03\/2019 00:30","date_login":"10\/06\/2019 00:40"}]';
var_dump(json_decode(remove_utf8_bom($string)));
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло